# Blocking GoogleBot in the Apache Configuration File

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

For my staging server, I'm trying to figure out a way to block search engine bots entirely, rather than an individual .htaccess file or robots.txt file. The idea is that it's out of sight and out of mind when creating a new site on the staging server. Is there a way to detect the bot's user agent using the apache module and block that connection on a sever-wide level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to block everything OTHER than a known-good testing agent string. That way you block bots you've never heard of. You could also block all but a known good set of IPs with %{REMOTE_ADDR}.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !YourTestingAgent
RewriteRule (.*) /404.html
```

Comment: That's a great idea. Are you able to place server-wide rewrite rules in the apache configuration file?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. The docs say it can go in at the "server config" level: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond